# RStudio show directory contents in file tab display window

Tags: r, file, rstudio, display

Is it possible to show a file directory using function/code? I find myself clicking through file structures to view a directory. I'd like to use some like this:

```
my_search_finding <- grep('search-pattern', list.files('~/some/long/directory/tree'))

new_function_to_view_files(my_search_finding)
```

Then the directory is opened in that viewer display and I can explore using the mouse.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows, you can use `choose.files`:

```
path <- '~/some/long/directory/tree'
selected.files <- choose.files(default=paste0(path, "/*.*"))
```

the `default` argument allows you to display files in a particular directory with a fully qualified file mask, see [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/choose.files.html).